# menuoptions responden igual - tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Estoy intentando hacer una funcion que me devuelva la cantidad de menuoptions que se desea junto a su nombre (etiqueta) pero al implementarla cuando selecciono una de las opciones de los menus se selecciona en los dos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al codigo lo estoy implementando desde diferentes modulos

Modulo de la funcion

```
def multiples_menuopciones(master, x, y, ancho = None, separacion = None, bg = None, fg = None, lista_nombres = [], lista_opciones = []):
    opciones = pd.DataFrame(lista_opciones)
    orden = opciones.shape
    etiqueta = 0
    variable = tk.StringVar()
    lista_menus = []
    sumatoria_x = 0
    ancho_menu = 0
    alto_etiqueta = 0
    ancho_etiqueta = 0
    aux = 0
    if separacion == None:
        separacion = 0
    
    for i in range(0, orden[0]):
        datos = []
        etiqueta = tk.Label(master, text = lista_nombres[i], bg = bg, fg = fg)
        alto_etiqueta = etiqueta.winfo_reqheight()
        ancho_etiqueta = etiqueta.winfo_reqwidth()
        for j in range(0, orden[1]):
            datos.append(opciones[j][i])
        print(lista_nombres[i])
        lista_nombres[i] = tk.OptionMenu(master, variable, *datos)
        if ancho == None:
            ancho_menu = lista_nombres[i].winfo_reqwidth()
        if ancho != None:
            ancho_menu = ancho
        
        #Alineación de la etiqueta 
        if ancho_menu < ancho_etiqueta:
            aux = ancho_etiqueta - ancho_menu
            aux = aux / 2
            etiqueta.place(x = x + sumatoria_x - aux, y = y)
            lista_nombres[i].place(x = x + sumatoria_x, y = y + alto_etiqueta, width = ancho)
            lista_nombres[i].configure(bd = 0, bg = bg, fg = fg)
        if ancho_menu > ancho_etiqueta:
            aux = ancho_menu - ancho_etiqueta
            aux = aux / 2
            etiqueta.place(x = x + sumatoria_x + aux, y = y)
            lista_nombres[i].place(x = x + sumatoria_x, y = y + alto_etiqueta, width = ancho)
            lista_nombres[i].configure(bd = 0, bg = bg, fg = fg)
        if ancho_menu == ancho_etiqueta:
            etiqueta.place(x = x + sumatoria_x, y = y)
            lista_nombres[i].place(x = x + sumatoria_x, y = y + alto_etiqueta, width = ancho)
            lista_nombres[i].configure(bd = 0, bg = bg, fg = fg)
        sumatoria_x = sumatoria_x + ancho_menu + separacion
        print(lista_nombres[i])
        lista_menus.append(lista_nombres[i])
        
    return lista_menus
```

Modulo desde donde se llama a la función. Esta dentro de una clase con sus correspondientes atributos predefinidos

```
        opciones = [["Compra", "Venta"], ["Ganancia", "Perdida"]]
        nombres = ["Tipo", "Resultado"]
        menus = util.multiples_menuopciones(self.__master, self.__ubicacion_x + sumatoria_x + self.__separacion + 10, self.__ubicacion_y + self.__sumatoria_y, 100, 20, "#2c2c2c", "beige", lista_nombres = nombres, lista_opciones = opciones)
```

Que puede estar pasando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que el problema está aquí:

```
variable = tk.StringVar()
```

Porque estás creando una sola variable para dos widgets, por lo que si lo modificas en uno, se modifica en el otro. La solución sería crear una variable por cada Widget que generas, lo puedes hacer en una lista

```
vars = []
for i in range(3): #por ejemplo, 3
    vars.append(tk.StringVar())
    tk.OptionMenu(master, vars[i], *datos)
```

Comment: Probe de esas maneras pero tampoco funciona

Comment: Ahhh, ya vi el problema. Es el `StringVar()`, tienes que crear un Stringvar diferente por cada widget, a menos que quieras que sean lo mismo... De todas maneras verifica cambiar solo el stringvar por si la respuesta inicial que te di está incorrecta, la modifico

Comment: Tal cual, era eso, Gracias!

Comment: Listo, recuerda marcar la respuesta si te ayudo!